# How should I use SonicNet.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have downlod examples of SonicNet.js for transferring data through sound but i dont know what to do.
Can anyone tell me what I have to do for transfering data through sound ( from laptop chrome to android chrome ), please.